# Macro to match specific identifiers for inline lookups

Tags: rust

Okay, writing my absolute first project in Rust. So, I have something like the following sort of setup:

```rs
use phf;
use std::str;

struct Values {
  a: Option<char>,
  b: Option<char>,
  c: Option<char>
}

static MAPPING: phf::Map<&'static str, Values> = phf::phf_map! {
  "some_key" => Values {
    a: Some('a'),
    b: Some('b'),
    c: None
  },

  "some_other_key" => Values {
    a: Some('1'),
    b: None,
    c: None
  },

  "some_third_key" => Values {
    a: None,
    b: Some('x'),
    c: Some('y')
  }
}

static NULL_VALUES: Values = Values {
  a: None,
  b: None,
  c: None
}

// Should return a &str for any given key/val
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! get_value {
  ($key: ident, $val: ident) => {{
    use crate::values::MAPPING;
    use std::str;
    let result = MAPPING.get("$key");
    if let Some(r) = result {
      if let Some(c) = r.$val {
        if let Ok(s) = str::from_utf8(%[c as u8]) { s } else { "" }
      } else { "" }
    } else { "" }
  }}
}
```

Which, it *works*, but it's just so much code and seeming like a whole lot of runtime overhead for no other reason than to organise some static values to avoid having to remember them all (in reality there are quite a lot and they're all raw codepoints). What I would love to be able to do is to just have a macro that takes a specific key/val and simply inlines either a known value or an empty value, but as far as I can tell there isn't any way to match a macro on a *specific* identifier, only *any* identifier... Is there any way that I can move all these lookups from runtime to compile time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros can pattern match against specific identifiers — just don't use `$`.

```rust
macro_rules! get_value {
    (some_key, a) => { Some('a') };
    (some_key, b) => { Some('b') };
    (some_key, c) => { None };
    (some_other_key, a) => { Some(1) };
    // ...
}
```

However, are you sure you don't want to just define a bunch of `const`ants?

```rust
const SOME_KEY_A: Option<char> = Some('a');
const SOME_KEY_B: Option<char> = Some('b');
```

Or expose the `Values` struct you already designed, which would then be accessed like `SOME_KEY.a`:

```rust
const SOME_KEY: Values = Values {
    a: Some('a'),
    b: Some('b'),
    c: None
};
```

That way, readers don't have to understand your macro to know that the data is just a constant. This will make your code easier to read and modify.

Comment: Yeah, I initially figured there would be too many of them to separate out thinking they would be a pain to import, but I've come to realise I just had a poor understanding of how Rust structures modules and... Yeah, constants are definitely the way to go :P Thanks!